# Filter in products.list api

Tags: google-apis-explorer, google-content-api

Is there a way to filter the results from
GET [https://shoppingcontent.googleapis.com/content/v2.1/{merchantId}/products](https://shoppingcontent.googleapis.com/content/v2.1/%7BmerchantId%7D/products) API.

eg: 1.expirationDate > somedate
2.last update date >somedate

Basically, I need to get products which get expired after a particular date and also products got updated after a particular date